# Run Code After Squarespace Popup Event Listener/Trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui, squarespace

I need to run some custom JS *after* the modal popup is loaded into the viewport.  What's the best way to piggy-back onto whatever event is triggered?

Once the pop-up is loaded, I need to execute something like this:

```js
jQuery(".newsletter-form[data-form-id='34li2j4j32il13l2j13ijl21i'] button").click(function (){ 
    console.log("Someone clicked the popup newsletter button.") 
});
```

Comment: This is tricky, but can be accomplished using mutation observers. Are you using Squarespace 7.0 or 7.1? If you're not sure, then what template are you using?

Comment: This was a bit difficult to find since this is a site I've been managing long after it was originally built.  It's called Boutique, but it's difficult to find.  This appears to be the correct one.  https://www.bradgood.net/templates/boutique

Comment: Alright, that's actually an old Squarespace 7.0 template.

Answer (score 0):

Because Squarespace doesn't provide the ability to hook into its own methods, we must use multiple [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), the second being setup within the first. Adding something like this via [Sitewide Footer Code Injection](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815908-Using-Code-Injection) should work:

```
<script>
(function() {
  new MutationObserver(function(m1,o1) {
    var popup = document.querySelector(".sqs-popup-overlay");
    if (popup) {
      o1.disconnect();
      new MutationObserver(function(m2,o2) {
        var btn;
        if (popup.classList.contains("visible")) {
          o2.disconnect();
          btn = popup.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
          btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
            console.log("Someone clicked the popup newsletter button.");
          });
        }
      }).observe(popup, {attributes:true, attributeFilter:['class']});
    }
  }).observe(document.body, {childList:true});
})();
</script>
```

The first mutation observer observes the body for the addition of the popup overlay element. If/When that element exists, the first mutation observer is disconnected and a second one is set to observe the class attribute of the popup until it contains the class "visible". If/When that happens, the second mutation observer can be disconnected and an event listener added to the popup submission button. Within the callback function of that event listener, your code is executed.